# Training in steps has any importance?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, train, siamese

I'm trying to train a Siamese network for face Verification and eventually I came across the `Contrastive Loss` method for embedding vector distancing (kinda... I guess...).

At the end, the model needs to yield `'1'` if two images has the `same` person in it, `else '0'`.

I though maybe I should first train the CNN to yield correct vectors with the "Contrastive Loss", and only after training was finished, add a FC layer with 1 output, and train again with the "Binary Cross Entropy", but (***and thats the question***) Is that mandatory? or I could train the model with both losses simultainously?

Does the steps on training the model has effects on the training?